# DataGridView show first row in half but last row complete

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

In the red box you can see the last row, whose upper half is visible. I want to show the last row full and the first (upper-most displayed) row in half.

AFAIK whatever you do (scroll, change current row, move up or down & ...) makes first row fully displayed and drops the redundant part of the last row.

Is there a way that I can do exactly vise versa? Show part of first row but whole of last row?

Comment: Why not expanding the DataGridView height to fit the whole row?

Comment: @etaiso Because then my form would not resize smoothly, I want to keep the smoothness of form resizing and also be able to show the first row complete when user scrolls down and show the last row complete when user scrolls up.

Comment: @etaiso maybe I do the expanding thing, I searched a lot and achieving what I desired is something around 0.01% possible, so I'll possibly work on the expand solution. Thanks. And now that you have given the solution I would accept the answer if you would have give one around expanding the grid on appropriate event.